# How to apply a spline basis matrix?

Tags: c++, vector, matrix, spline

1) I have a bunch of spline control points ranging from P0 to PN.
2) I have a spline basis matrix.

How do I, given 2 control point indices and a t value, apply the basis matrix to get an interpolated position?

Now I keep seeing the following form:

```
                [b00, b01, b02, b03] [p0]
                [b04, b05, b06, b07] [p1]
[t^3, t^2, t, 1][b08, b09, b10, b11].[p2]
                [b12, b13, b14, b15] [p3]
```

So I'm assuming p0 etc are my control points.  I also assume that this is per component (ie x,y,z).  However I'm totally unsure of what exactly I'm doing with the t values.

Can anyone explain this for me?  I'm most probably just being an idiot :)

I'm using C++, and have many maths classes, so I'd rather not have the maths expanded out.  It would be much more useful to just understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's per component, so each p is a single number. They are the x-coordinates (say) of four consecutive control points.

Your matrix thing is simply the product of three matrices: ordinary matrix multiplication. So it's a sum: t^3.(b00.p0+b01.p1+...) + t^2.(b04.p0+b05.p1+...) + etc. And that's your coordinate value at the given value of t. (t^3 means t*t*t rather than t XOR 3 like in C, of course.)

The range of values of t will typically be from 0 to 1 on each segment of the spline. The b-values will then be such that the value at t=1 for one segment equals the value at t=0 for the next (and hence doesn't depend on the first control point of the first segment, or the last control point of the next).

Comment: So effectively I am doing a veector matrix multiply and getting a resultant vector.  I then multiply that with the 4 position's component (eg x) to get my final scalar value that is x?